# Cookie http-only in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I can't delete cookies, This is my logout method in controller ...

```
@GetMapping ("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<String> logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException{
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        System.out.println(cookies);
        if (cookies == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Logout failed: JWT cookie not found.");
        } else {
            if (!Arrays.stream(cookies).map(Cookie::getName).anyMatch(x -> x.equals("jwt"))) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Logout failed: JWT cookie not found");
            } else {
                logoutService.logout(request, response, authentication);
                Cookie jwtCookie = new Cookie("jwt", null);
                jwtCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
                jwtCookie.setPath("/");
                jwtCookie.setMaxAge(0);
                jwtCookie.setDomain("localhost");
                response.addCookie(jwtCookie);
                return ResponseEntity.ok("User logout success.");
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried really hard to follow the instructions, This is my logout method in service

```
 @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        String jwt = null;
        Cookie jwtToken = Arrays.stream(cookies).filter(x->x.getName().equals("jwt")).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
        jwt= jwtToken.getValue();
        System.out.println(jwt);
        var storedToken = tokenRepository.findByToken(jwt).orElseThrow(null);
        if(storedToken!=null) {
            storedToken.setExpired(true);
            storedToken.setRevoked(true);
            tokenRepository.save(storedToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }
```